# Suggestion on CSS Image Sprite

Tags: css, user-interface

I work on an application similar to Google event calendar.
Name of the application is  My Team Event Calendar .
Developed this using jQuery Full calendar plugin.
In a calendar ,for each day ,i would display which teammember of mine is outofoffice(is an employee workfromhome/sick/vacation).

For each of this outofoffice status,i have an icon,displaying the purpose of  it.
I have 72 around outofoffice statuses ,which would get icons source from database\
I have all 72 stauts with their associate image icon source in db as "images/pill.png"
Every time ,i get the information from server about a team .for each day i would get team member name,out of office status and image associated with the status.

Consider if my calendar is full for whole 31 days ,and for each day i would have about 10 employees. For each of this out of office status ,i would get a image (this means many http requests for image icons for out of office status).

Can you please suggest is it good to maintain css image sprite.But i have a disadvantage at any point of time a new leave type can be added with new image icon ,which imposes an immediate change in the image sprite.(maintaining/modifying an image sprite is not that easy)

If not image sprite can you please suggest what would be a better solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your scenario correctly this would be an excellent place to use a sprite. A large set of small images is an ideal use case and using a single sprit will reduce HTTP traffic significantly. Sprites may seem like a little overhead initially but it's not bad once you get used to it and the performance is well worth the few extra minutes to compose the sprite.

Keep a PSD (or some other original source) for the sprite handy. When you need to make edits, add a new icon, etc. then update the PSD and export your new sprite PNG.

Another option to consider is icon fonts. You might look at something like [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), Bootstrap's [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) or a tool like [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/). Icon fonts have a lot of advantages, chiefly scalability and colorization. If you don't need that, though, sprites work just fine.